# Javascript objects listening to their own events

Tags: javascript, events, object

I have been playing with event driven javascript lately, and have wondered if it's a good/bad thing for objects listening for their own events as a way of abstracting and simplifying internal logic.

Consider the following:

```
function MyModule(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.data    = {};

    this.setListeners();
    //...
}

MyModule.prototype = new EventEmitter;
MyModule.prototype.constructor = MyModule;

MyModule.prototype.updateBasket = function() {
    var self = this,
        url  = this.options.url;

    $.ajax(url)
        .done(function(data) {
            self.emit('basketupdate:success', data);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, err) {
            self.emit('basketupdate:error', err);
        })
        .complete(function() {
            self.emit('basketupdate:complete');
        });
};

MyModule.prototype.setListeners = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.on('basketupdate:success', function(data) {
        // ... do something on success
        self.data = data;
    });

    this.on('basketupdate:success', function(data) {
        // ... do something else on success
        console.dir(data);
    });

    this.on('basketupdate:error', function() {
        // ... do something to handle the error
    });
};

var module = new MyModule({
    url: '/path/to/request'
});

module.updateBasket();
```

A simple module with an ajax request. I could quite easily put all the logic in the corresponding callback, or even map callbacks to internal methods. However I'm quite liking this approach to simplifying the code.

Are there downsides or potential problems to structuring the code in the way that I haven't considered. Or would this be seen as an anti-pattern with events only intended to be listened to from elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe you should consider asking this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I would not see potential problems with this code. Emitting events to listen to by the module itself and outside is done in several jQuery libraries as well.

Comment: Thanks - I did not know about codereview! I have posted this over there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but it's not really useful.

This code is just easier to read:

```
MyModule.prototype.updateBasket = function() {
    var self = this,
        url  = this.options.url;

    $.ajax(url)
        .done(this.done)
        .fail(this.fail)
        .complete(this.complete);
};

MyModule.prototype.done = function(data) {
    // Do something when done
};

MyModule.prototype.fail = function(data) {
    // Do something when request failed
};

MyModule.prototype.complete = function(data) {
    // Do something no matter what
};
```

And you could give more meaningful names to your methods.

Event emitters are useful when you're playing with different objects that you don't want to link together.

Comment: I agree in this simplified context. But once objects get bigger and more complex then methods like `done` could be handling many different things. Using listeners I can keep logic cleaner and more separated into individual concerns - just playing around with ideas really.

Comment: @leepowell you're going to have different listeners for different events anyway. Using functions is the way to go if you want clean, separated concerns. It's what they were invented for, after all.